# "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, docker-buildkit

I just want to build a dockerfile from a different directory, I tried the following command

`docker build -f C:/Users/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/Dockerfile`

and

`docker build -f C://Users/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/Dockerfile`

Both of them yield the same error

`"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You're not passing the required context directory, only the `-f .../Dockerfile` option.  The default `-f` value is `Dockerfile` in the named context directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze But isn't the `-f PATH` the context directory ? what else should be added ?

Comment: No, that option specifies a non-default Dockerfile to use; it's separate from the required context-directory option.

Answer (score 17):

You should provide the context, current directory for instance: `.`.

`docker build -f C://Users/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/Dockerfile -t something .`

Comment: why should we add "." at the end, isn't that what -f string part does ?

Comment: can you try a single slash after `C:/`? the `.` specify the context, the relative path for your dockerfile. All your commands in the Dockerfile will be relative to this current folder

Comment: so through -f we are changing the current folder ? in that case "." is mandatory in every build command ?

Comment: no, you need `-f <some Dockerfile> if you don't have dockerfile named `Dockerfile` in your current directory. If you will copy that file to your current directory you won't have to specify that and `docker build -t something .` will be enough

Answer (score 0):

It is interpreting the C://Users/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/Dockerfile in that line as the value for the -f switch (or option)

If you remove that -f it should rather interpret it as the path to the Dockerfile

when i type docker build at the terminal, i see

```
Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

im not sure what the -f switch does, but when i build images, I am pretty sure I do this

```
docker image build -t tagname /path/to/Dockerfile
```

Comment: That second command isn't the path to the Dockerfile, it's the path to the build context.

Comment: the problem is `.`